# Unimodular matrices $M_{E_8}$ and $M_{\operatorname{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-matrices, unimodular-matrices

Consider two unimodular matrices $M_{E_8}$ and $M_{\operatorname{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$:

$$M_{E_8} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \cr
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 \cr
\end{pmatrix}.$$

$$
M_{\operatorname{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 4
\end{array}
\right).$$
The $\operatorname{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ means that a basis for the lattice is given by the roots of $SO(32)$, but 
with the root corresponding to the vector
representation replaced by the weight of one of the
spinor representations.

It seems that the following two unimodular matrices $M_{E_8}  \oplus M_{E_8}$ and $M_{\operatorname{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$ are related by certain $SL(16,\mathbb{Z})$
basis change. That is called this basis change matrix $U$.

> question 1. If it is true, can we rewrite: $$M_{E_8} \oplus M_{E_8}=U M_{\operatorname{Spin}(32)/\mathbb{Z}_2} U^\dagger?$$
>   with $U \in SL(16,\mathbb{Z})$.
>   (optional: what is this $U$?)

-

> question 2. Is it true that the canonical form of this unimodular indefinite symmetric integral matrices can be rewritten as 
>   $$\bigl( {\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 1 &0 \\
> 0 & -1 
> \end{smallmatrix}}  \bigl) \oplus \bigl( {\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 1 &0 \\
> 0 & -1 
> \end{smallmatrix}}  \bigl) \oplus \bigl( {\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 1 &0 \\
> 0 & -1 
> \end{smallmatrix}}  \bigl) \oplus \cdots$$
>   and 
>   $$
> \bigl( {\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 0 &1 \\
> 1 & 0  
> \end{smallmatrix}} \bigl) \oplus \bigl( {\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 0 &1 \\
> 1 & 0  
> \end{smallmatrix}} \bigl)\oplus \bigl( {\begin{smallmatrix} 
> 0 &1 \\
> 1 & 0  
> \end{smallmatrix}} \bigl) \oplus \cdots
> $$
>   and a set of all positive (or negative) coefficients $E_8$ lattices, $M_{E_8}$?